# Passing integers from file to array

Tags: java, arrays, file, integer

Someone Can explain me why this piece of code doesn't works?
My array doesn't get filled with anything -.-

```
    Integer[] tab1 = new Integer[401];
    int[][] tab2 = new int[20][20];
    File fr;
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    fr = new File("problem11");
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(fr);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            // System.out.printf("%d ", sc.nextInt());
            tab1[i] = sc.nextInt();

            i++;
            System.out.print(tab1[i]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That is most likely because `problem11` does not exist in the default directory for the location from which you run your program.

Comment: Maybe sc has no next lines, maybe there's a problem while reading, ...
Does your code go into the while loop ? Is there a stacktrace ?

Comment: if it has integers then you should get for hasNextInt rather than hasNext. You might be getting InputMismatchException?

Comment: Can you show us what "problem11" looks like.  My guess is that the file is missing carriage return/new line SO sc.hasNext() or sc.nextInt() evaluates as FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

You're displaying the next array element which hasnt been populated yet

```
i++;
System.out.print(tab1[i]);
```

should be

```
System.out.print(tab1[i++]);
```